# Pi Hole ignoring rate limiting settings

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, pi-hole

I'm having issues getting my Pi Hole to respect rate limiting settings. After some investigation I noticed that the values under Settings - DNS were going into the pihole-FTL.conf file as `RATE_LIMIT=` but looking at the logs on startup the configuration section would always say `RATE_LIMIT: Rate-limiting client making more than 1000 queries in 60 seconds` no matter what values I put into the settings/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The first non-commented line in my pihole-FTL.conf was something I couldn't find anything about: `FTLCONF_RATE_LIMIT=300`

After commenting out that line, the FTL log finally started reflecting the actual settings in the file and following the rate limiting setting.